# Alfresco - right custom ID generation

Tags: solr, alfresco

I need advice how to properly generate my own unique ID in Alfresco.
My ID is created unique for every site, some prefix (created by date and some property) + incremental suffix.
I store this values in datalists in every site. I have this already working code as behavior onCreateNode():

```
public String getInvoiceNextValue(String siteShortName, String prefix) {
       // Find generator for given projectType
       String query = "PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:" + siteShortName + "//*\" AND TYPE:\"test:myDatalist\" AND @test:prefix:\"" + prefix + "\"";
       ResultSet resultSet = searchService.query(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE, SearchService.LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO, query);
       // If doesn't exist, creates one, otherwise return next value
       if (resultSet.length() < 1) {
           return createDocumentCounter(siteShortName, prefix);
       } else if (resultSet.length() == 1) {
           NodeRef counterRef = resultSet.getNodeRef(0);
           String newCounterValue = (String) nodeService.getProperty(counterRef, MyDatalistModel.PROP_SUFFIX);
           int newIntValue = Integer.parseInt(newCounterValue) + 1;
           newCounterValue = String.format("%04d", newIntValue);

           nodeService.setProperty(counterRef,  MyDatalistModel.PROP_SUFFIX, newCounterValue);
           return newCounterValue;
       } else {
           throw new AlfrescoRuntimeException("resultSet.length() > 2! Please Fix it!");
       }
   }
```

But i have problem when more documents are created at one time.
Specially when no row with my test:prefix exist and then function createDocumentCounter() is called.
It takes some time that Alfresco FTS query return my new created row.
So it happens that more documents create own row with same values.

I thing that problem is in indexing of solr which take few seconds. So...
Is my approach right? Can i somehow configure solr better?
Or should i use some another approach? How you are dealing with creating customers ID?

Comment: Why not use the Node Service to list the collection folder? Or store the counter node somewhere with a well-known ID that you can just fetch?

Comment: I don't have all documents in one folder and sometimes I need manually edit my counter. So I think that Node Service s not good for me.
Use counter node with well-known ID would be problem to migrate between environments (DEV/TEST/PROD). And I use more numerical series so I don't know how to properly save under one node...

Comment: You can use a well-known name or association within the site to store them